# Node.js EventEmitter2; How to remove listeners added with onAny

Tags: javascript, eventemitter

How can I remove all event listeners that listen on *any* event?

I've tried `removeAllListeners()` but it's not working. Am I missing something?

```js
const ee = new EventEmitter2()
  
ee.onAny(() => console.log('hello was fired'))
setInterval(() => ee.emit('hello'), 500)

setTimeout(() => {
  ee.removeAllListeners()
  console.log('removed all listeners')
}, 1500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eventemitter2@5.0.1/lib/eventemitter2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this was downvoted.  It has the relevant code and looks like it [follows the API](https://github.com/EventEmitter2/EventEmitter2#emitterremovealllistenersevent) but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @zero298 someone tried to answer it with a nonsensical answer and when I called him out he started pushing close votes and all. Go figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the API for this library is somewhat confusing.  To deregister `onAny()` listeners, you use [`offAny()`](https://github.com/EventEmitter2/EventEmitter2#emitteroffanylistener).

Drilling down into the source reveals that `removeAllListeners()` doesn't really touch the `_all` array that tracks the listeners for any event.  It just runs `init()` and `configure()` on the listener again none of which touches that `_all` array.

Also note your issue on the GitHub page here: [removeAllListeners does not remove listeners added with onAny #235](https://github.com/EventEmitter2/EventEmitter2/issues/235)

If you want to actually remove them all do something like this:

```js
const ee = new EventEmitter2();

ee.onAny(() => console.log("any event was fired"));
ee.on("hello", () => console.log("hello event was fired"));

setInterval(() => ee.emit("hello"), 500);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Removing any listener");
  ee.offAny();
}, 1500);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Removing all listeners");
  ee.removeAllListeners();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eventemitter2@5.0.1/lib/eventemitter2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to use both, as per the comment here: https://github.com/EventEmitter2/EventEmitter2/issues/235#issuecomment-397645153. I'm sorry I didn't link to the Issue I opened and led you down this rabbit hole. You are correct, that's the proper way of doing it.